# Sequence of monotonic functions $f_n$ converging to a contimuous function f pointwise, is $f$ continuous?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ define a sequence of functions $(f_n)$. Assume it to converge pointwise to a continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, and $f_n(x)$ is a monotonic decreasing function for all $n$ and for all $x$ belonging to $X$. I eed to prove that $(f_n)$ converge to $f$ uniformly.

I thought that $(f_n)$ may continuous. because we know that if $f_n$ is continuous and converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is continuous. I try to prove like this:
  $$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|\leq|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|<ε$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I did my best to make your text readable. For your next question, please at least include mathematical expressions between dollar signs... it is one of the most fundamental conventions of Latex.

Comment: I think that the compactness of the metric space $X$ plays the main role: [if $f$ is continuous on compact metric space, then it is uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine–Cantor_theorem)

Comment: If $f_n$'s are continuous this is just Dini's Theorem.

Comment: thanks to Jean Marie and sorry about that, i use this website for the first time, and i am not a native speaker, so... i will try to do better last time, thanks again. @Jean Marie

Comment: I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

No. For a counterexample, take $X = [0,2]$, let $f_n$ be $\frac{1}{n}I_{[0,1]} + \frac{1}{2n}I_{[0,2]}$, where $I_A$ is the identifier function of $A$, so $$I_A(x) \ \left\{\array{1,&x\in A\\0,&x\not\in A.}\right.$$ 
Clearly $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, but none of the $f_n$ are continuous.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have not seen this counterexample before.